# Canon EDSDK Crashes after start

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to write a simple camara app. I created a new Project and add the EDSDK headers and the lib. Also i have added the init command EdsInitializeSDK().

test.pro

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = Test
TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui

LIBS += -L".\EDSDK.lib"
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include <EDSDK.h>
#include <EDSDKErrors.h>
#include <EDSDKTypes.h>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    EdsError err=EDS_ERR_OK;
    err = EdsInitializeSDK();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

the main.cpp and mainwindow.h are not modified.

it compiled, but when i want to start the programm it crash without any error.

In debug i become the error 0xc0000135

I use the Canon_Camara_SDK_Kit_v2_14 with Qt on Win 7.

The EDSDK.lib are in the src and in the build Folder.

I have no Idea whats wrong

Thanks!

Comment: `LIBS += -L".\EDSDK.lib"` is wrong. `-L` is for the library path, not the library name. I think you confuse it with `-l`.

Comment: Ok now i have changed to total path and without optins (and i tried some options), but it still crashes 
`LIBS += "C:\Users\Willy\Desktop\Test\camlib\Library\EDSDK.lib")`

Comment: Still wrong IMHO because you should use `-LC:\Users\Willy\Desktop\Test\camlib\Library -lEDDSK`, but I think it would be useful to get more information about the crash.

Comment: `Starte C:\Users\Willy\Desktop\build-Test-Desktop_Qt_5_2_1_MinGW_32bit-Debug\debug\Test.exe...
The Programm is crashed.
C:\Users\Willy\Desktop\build-Test-Desktop_Qt_5_2_1_MinGW_32bit-Debug\debug\Test.exe is crashed` this is the error when i start the programm. whe i debug: `During startup Programm exited with code 0xc0000135` and no more errors or outputs